# Primefaces - generate subtotal and total in editable datatable according car brands

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

Using the examples from [Primefaces DataTable - Edit](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) I've changed the Year column to display Prices instead. Added a `sortBy="#{car.brand}"` filter in `<p:dataTable>` and a `<p:summaryRow>` to display a calculated subtotal for every car brand (according to [Primefaces DataTable - Summary Row](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/summaryRow.xhtml)). And then a footer to display the calculated grand total.

```
<f:facet name="footer">
    <h:outputText id="carstotal" value="Total: $#{dtEditView.totalSales}" />
</f:facet>
```

For calculating the total I made this method in **EditView.java**:

```
public Integer getTotalSales() {
    Integer total = 0;
    for (Car car : cars2) {
        total += car.getPrice();
    }
    return total;
}
```

But I'm stuck on **how to calculate in another method the subtotal according the same brands. Is there a way to do it if the datatable price cells are editable?** Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't get what the grand total has to do with your actual problem. Can you include the relevant code for the brand total?

Comment: Have a look at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml

Comment: @JasperdeVries Actually I got the total price of all cars using the getTotalSales() method from above. But cars are randomly generated and they have brands associated. I was wondering if there is a way to get also "the subtotals" according brands. E.g.: If there are 3 Jaguar cars in the table another method should calculate the "subtotal" for these. Hope I was more explicit now. Meanwhile I'll look at your given link. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the method for getting the subtotals of same brands. But when I change the price value in a cell it updates only the total. I added following code in **EditView.java**:

```
public void init() {
    ...
        cars2.stream().filter(car -> !brands.contains(car.getBrand())).forEach(car -> brands.add(car.getBrand()));
        Collections.sort(brands);
    ...
}

public Integer getSubTotalSales() {
    Integer total = 0;
    for (Car car : cars2) {
        if (Objects.equals(car.getBrand(), brands.get(callCounter))) {
            total += car.getPrice();
        }
    }
    callCounter++;
    return total;
}

public Integer getTotalSales() {
    Integer total = 0;
    for (Car car : cars2) {
            total += car.getPrice();
    }
    return total;
}
```

In **cars.xhtml**

```
<h:form id="form">
    <p:growl id="msgs" autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true"/>

    ...

    <p:remoteCommand name="onCellEdit" process="@this" update=":form:cars2:carssubtotal :form:cars2:carstotal" />

    <p:dataTable id="cars2" var="car" value="#{dtEditView.cars2}" sortBy="#{car.brand}" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellCars">

    ...

        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{dtEditView.onCellEdit}" update=":form:msgs" oncomplete="onCellEdit()" />

        <p:summaryRow>
            <p:column colspan="3" style="text-align:right">
                <h:outputText value="Sub-Total: " />
            </p:column>
            <p:column>
                <h:outputText id="carssubtotal" value="#{dtEditView.subTotalSales}">
                    <f:convertNumber type="currency" currencySymbol="$" />
                </h:outputText>
            </p:column>
        </p:summaryRow>

        <f:facet name="footer">
            <h:outputText id="carstotal" value="Total: $#{dtEditView.totalSales}" />
        </f:facet>

    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```